# multiple criteria case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that contains duplicate records due to deals that have been cancelled; in some cases I want to keep the cancelled record, and in others I want to omit it (if a customer pulls out of a deal without a new buyer, I want to keep it - if a new buyer is found, I want to omit it. This way, one record exists for each vehicle). I'll have to amend the query on a case by case basis.

with the little that I know, I think it should look something like the following, but I can't get it to work.

```
case [StockNo] when 'XXXXXX' and [FiWipStatusCode] = 'C' then 'omit' 
end as 'Filter'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **searched case syntax**:

```
case when [StockNo]= 'XXXXXX' and [FiWipStatusCode] = 'C' then 'omit'end 
  as 'Filter'
```

From [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
Simple CASE expression:   
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END 


Searched CASE expression:  
CASE  
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Expand the conditions in the `case` *expression*:

```
(case when [StockNo] = 'XXXXXX' and [FiWipStatusCode] = 'C' then 'omit' 
 end) as Filter
```

Also, don't use single quotes around the the column alias.  That just confuses column aliases and strings.

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you so much for taking the time to help a stranger. Have a great weekend!